# Why is "align" not a valid attribute of div but still works?

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I set 'align="center"' in  and it comes up with a green line under it that says it is not a "valid attribute of element div". How can this be if it still has effect on it?

```
<div align="center" ></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

[It used to be valid](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/SPSD-html32-20180315/#div). It was [deprecated in 1997](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40-971218/present/graphics.html#adef-align) and made [obsolete and non-conforming](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#element-attrdef-div-align) in 2014.

Browsers are backwards compatible so old webpages don't break.

Don't use it. Since 1996 we have CSS instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `align` attribute is not valid on `div` or most other tags in HTML5. It was valid markup back in HTML 3.2 and earlier, but while still works, has been invalid syntax for many years in HTML4, XHTML or HTML5.

Browsers generally have good backwards compatibility for earlier versions of HTML and XHTML and their features, especially more popular features like the `align` tag. Despite the compatibility, you should always aim for valid syntax whenever possible.

If you need to centre objects, you should use CSS. You can either use a `margin: 0 auto;` CSS rule on the element to centre it (note: this is an inline example, but you should probably use a CSS class instead):

```
<div style="width: 70%; margin: 0 auto;">
  ...
</div>
```

Or you can also look at the newer CSS Box Alignment features (i.e. flexbox), depending what you're centring.

- [Example of working `margin:0 auto;`](https://learnlayout.com/margin-auto.html) (note: requires a width set on the element to work)
- [CSS Box Alignment Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Alignment)